# Call an URL with Auth Token with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, jwt, basic-authentication, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API to Login to my Webapp using Baisc Authentication. After a successful login the server returns a token as a json object. I am then using this token to make requests to other API Endpoints. Those endpoints just show a webpage if the request contains a valid token.

Everything works fine but nothing shows up in the browser after I make a successful call with the fetch API..

If I call the API endpoint in a REST Client it returns the html which seems to be fine. The problem seems to be that the browser should call the url instead of just fetch the html..

Here is my code. I am getting the "Success"-Alert - so everything seems to work fine. But I need the browser to show the result as a new page (some kind of a direct call of the url with the token in the header).

```
function login(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  let url = URL + 'login';
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
  fetch(url, {method:'GET',
          headers: headers,
         })
  .then(function(response)
  {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      let error = document.getElementById("login-error");
      error.innerHTML = "Username/Password incorrect.";
    }
  })
  .then(function(json)
  {
    if (typeof(json) !== "undefined") {
      startWebapp(json.token);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

function startWebapp(token) {
  let url = URL + 'webapp/overview';
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  fetch(url, {method:'GET',
headers: headers,
})
.then(function(response) {
  alert("Success!");
  return response;
});
}
```

How can I achieve that the browser actually calls the url with the API token and opens it if the fetch is successful?

Comment: This is an ajax request, the browser won't redirect you anywhere. Does the request return an HTML string? If so, you could just append this string somewhere in the DOM. If you need a new page to be displayed, don't use ajax, but rather a "standard" http request.

Comment: Yes the request returns html and this html is the webpage I want to show. The problem is that I want the browser to open a new page which is secured with JWTAuthentication. The workflow is: Browser gets to login page, after successful login the token is returned, browser needs to open a new page and send the token with the request. Any idea how to achieve this? Or should I change my logic for the web app login part? By the way: What do you mean with "standard" http request? And how to achieve this with a JWT Token?

Comment: It seems to me you're confusing something here. If your ajax request just returns HTML as a string, this means that you can manipulate the DOM using that string, but it doesn't mean the server returned a complete HTML document(which would be "a new page"). I think you need to choose: Either do all your "page" manipulations within one page using JS, or just render new pages from the server, and keep the auth in some session

Comment: I am actually rendering pages on the Server. I am using the Slim Framework and the routes are returning html pages. The Login page is rendered just like the page I am accessing with the fetch request (/webapp/overview). So I am expecting the browser to show the page. If I just want to open a page which is secured via Tokens - How could I do that? I need to pass the token in the Authorization Header.

Comment: Well the browser wont show any page, because it's not receiving a page- it's just receiving a string(which could be a page..). I would just use a normal POST form, with no ajax, and store the token in localStorage or something like it.

Comment: Well ok. But this would not change the problem: How to open an url which is protected and expects a token in the header?

Comment: i think this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286781/jwt-token-with-ajax-non-ajax-jquery

Comment: I already read that thread. But this doesn't seem to help. How to tell the browser to open the url in the same window if the url is expecting a token? I don't even want to use Ajax. Just a simple command like open URL with Auth Header appended.

Comment: To be honest, i've never dealt with such a situation, so i don't know. I was always either relying on the PHP $_SESSION functionality, which sets a cookie(with the session id) automatically for you, or with JWT using AJAX, in a single page app. Maybe you should rely on something built-in that php provides you with, like the session(assuming this is a server-side rendered app as you said)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching for a solution:
This is actually not possible with JavaScript nor the fetch API. For me the (easiest) solution is to save the token in a cookie. The server then searches for a token in the cookie and uses it for authentication/authorization. This works pretty well and I don't need to send the token on every request.

Hope that helps.